# Importance of return this; in plugin function?

Tags: jquery, return-value

I am learning Jquery and I am trying to get how to make a plugin.

```
$.fn.myfun = function(options) {
        if (typeof options === 'string') {
            callOption.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            initElements.call(this, options);
        }
        return this;
    };
```

I am not able to understand why there is a statement **return this** ? Why do we return it?

Comment: So you can chain other jQuery methods after calling your plugin

Comment: Chaining other Jquery methods means?

Comment: I've written a proper answer with an example `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is so you or the end user of your plugin can chain other jQuery methods after calling your plugin. For example:

```
$('.foo').myFun().slideToggle();
```

Returning `this` returns a jQuery object in this case, maintaining access to all the methods jQuery has.

Comment: OK....So this is the crap it does :)... Thanks a lot for the answer friend. Keep saving people from lots of frustration. Thank you